how to compare 2 dataframes and populate boolean value
how to compare 2 dataframes and populate boolean value
check whether individual pattern from dict is present or whole string is present in second dataframe.
df1 = pl.DataFrame({
   "A": ["a", "b", "a", "c","a","c","a","b","b"], 
   "B": [23,45,60,50,56,44,34,30,97], 
   "C": ["{'pattern1':['a','score1'],'pattern2':['df','text1']}",
        "{'pattern3':['abc','score1']}",
        "{'pattern1':['a','score2'],'pattern4':['df','text2']}",
        "{'pattern5':['a','score2'],'pattern6':['gh','text1'],'pattern7':['gh','text1']}",
        "{'pattern8':['a','score1']}",
        "{'pattern9':['a','score1'],'pattern10':['df','text1']}",
        "{'pattern11':['a','score1']}",
        "{'pattern12':['a','score1'],'pattern13':['df','text1']}",
        "{'pattern3':['a','score1'],'pattern5':['df','text1']}"]
})

shape: (9, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C                                                                               │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---                                                                             │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ str                                                                             │
╞═════╪═════╪═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ a   ┆ 23  ┆ {'pattern1':['a','score1'],'pattern2':['df','text1']}                           │
│ b   ┆ 45  ┆ {'pattern3':['abc','score1']}                                                   │
│ a   ┆ 60  ┆ {'pattern1':['a','score2'],'pattern4':['df','text2']}                           │
│ c   ┆ 50  ┆ {'pattern5':['a','score2'],'pattern6':['gh','text1'],'pattern7':['gh','text1']} │
│ a   ┆ 56  ┆ {'pattern8':['a','score1']}                                                     │
│ c   ┆ 44  ┆ {'pattern9':['a','score1'],'pattern10':['df','text1']}                          │
│ a   ┆ 34  ┆ {'pattern11':['a','score1']}                                                    │
│ b   ┆ 30  ┆ {'pattern12':['a','score1'],'pattern13':['df','text1']}                         │
│ b   ┆ 97  ┆ {'pattern3':['a','score1'],'pattern5':['df','text1']}                           │
└─────┴─────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
df2 = pl.DataFrame({
   "A": ["a", "a", "b", "b","a","c"], 
   "valid_patterns": ['pattern1',
       "{'pattern1': ['a', 'score2'], 'pattern4': ['df', 'text2']}",
        "{'pattern3':['abc','score1']}",
        'pattern3',
        "{'pattern11': ['a', 'score1']}",
        'pattern9']
})
shape: (6, 2)
┌─────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ A   ┆ valid_patterns                                             │
│ --- ┆ ---                                                        │
│ str ┆ str                                                        │
╞═════╪════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ a   ┆ pattern1                                                   │
│ a   ┆ {'pattern1': ['a', 'score2'], 'pattern4': ['df', 'text2']} │
│ b   ┆ {'pattern3':['abc','score1']}                              │
│ b   ┆ pattern3                                                   │
│ a   ┆ {'pattern11': ['a', 'score1']}                             │
│ c   ┆ pattern9                                                   │
└─────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

ouput:
Based on Column A , need to check column c values whether full dict or any one key in dict need to be present in valid_patterns column of second dataframe  for column A.
output = pl.DataFrame({
   "A": ["a", "b", "a", "c","a","c","a","b","b"], 
   "B": [23,45,60,50,56,44,34,30,97], 
   "C": ["{'pattern1':['a','score1'],'pattern2':['df','text1']}",
        "{'pattern3':['abc','score1']}",
        "{'pattern1':['a','score2'],'pattern4':['df','text2']}",
        "{'pattern5':['a','score2'],'pattern6':['gh','text1'],'pattern7':['gh','text1']}",
        "{'pattern8':['a','score1']}",
        "{'pattern9':['a','score1'],'pattern10':['df','text1']}",
        "{'pattern11':['a','score1']}",
        "{'pattern12':['a','score1'],'pattern13':['df','text1']}",
        "{'pattern3':['a','score1'],'pattern5':['df','text1']}"],
    "VALID": [True,True,True,False,False,True,True,False,False]
})


How are you creating df1? Column C has a dtype of object which will not happen using the code you've shown. (Also, you can increase the formatting defaults to display the full repr e.g. pl.Config(fmt_table_cell_list_len=10, fmt_str_lengths=80))

Is there a particular reason you are putting stringified Python dicts inside of Polars? Could you not use JSON instead for example?
